# start a freeRTOS task with a function

Tags: task, freertos, esp-idf

is it safe to create a task with a variable?

```
TaskHandle_t blablaTaskHandle= NULL;
...
bool startTask = readAVariable();

if(startTask ){
    xTaskCreate(&blabla, "blabla", 2048, NULL, 2, &blablaTaskHandle);
}
```

And also suspend it and resume:

```
 // this is in the main loop 
    bool suspendTask = true;
    if( suspendTask && (blablaTaskHandle!= NULL)){                  
        vTaskSuspend(blablaTaskHandle);
    }
    else{
        vTaskResume(blablaTaskHandle);
    }
```

Comment: Could you elaborate your problem a bit? I'm afraid it's not very clear and hard to help you right now. Are you trying to let a task "wait" for some even or action to happen?

Comment: What is `&blabla`? If it's not a pointer to the task function then it's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You create a task with a function call, not a variable, so I'm not sure what you are asking.  From the [API documentation](https://www.freertos.org/a00125.html), and the hundreds of provided examples, it looks like your use of the first parameter to xTaskCreate() is probably wrong.